# codeigniter pagination is not working and nginx shows not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, pagination

i am creating pagination in codeigniter with these config in my controller.

```
$config = array();
$config['base_url'] = base_url()."api/EtransProxy/getSettlement";
$config['total_rows'] = $this->Do_model->totalFiltered();
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
```

and this message shows up :

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.10.2
```

my nginx.conf :

```
location /eTransportation/{
            alias  /var/www/eTransportation/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /eTransportation/index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            }
        }
```

i can't find the solution for this, i hope you guys can solve my problem

edit :
finally i found the solution, and the error was my queries and model for my database

Answer (score 0):

Use this nginx.conf for your site, Right config for your situation must look simular to this:

```
server {
        server_name yoursitename.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/flo2go/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
            expires           15d;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/www/flo2go/index.php;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI      $request_uri;
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
         }
    }
```